# rebar generate fails after compile successes

Tags: erlang, rebar

I am new to rebar and try to create a demo app to understand the flow. 
I have downloaded rebar & ran bootstrap.
I created a project according to this manual:
[justenough-otp1](http://zotonic.com/docs/0.9/manuals/cookbook/justenough-otp1.html)

when I run the compile it compiles all the files and when it runs it.
when i try to generate the app it gives me the following error:

```
WARN:  'generate' command does not apply to directory /users/olive/poznov/Downloads/rebar-master/learn/apps
Command 'generate' not understood or not applicable
```

i tried to run

> ./rebar generate

from both the parent folder and apps folder (of course changing the path in the rebar.config file)

any ideas what might cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The generate command is used to build a release. It is much more than a simple application: it contains the VM, your application and all the libraries and dependencies needed. So it needs some more information to be generated. You can look at [Erlang rebar tutorial: generating releases and upgrades](http://www.metabrew.com/article/erlang-rebar-tutorial-generating-releases-upgrades) or [LYSE release with reltool](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word#am-i-an-executable-yet) for more information (learning from the Eralang documentation is much more difficult)